# Datatable search by ID of username

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Objective:** row Data filter according to specific column data (username) values.

**Action:** searching data table. **Search string:** ID = username

I have following in code.gs.

```
 function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
 var range = sheet.getDataRange()
 var values = range.getDisplayValues()
 Logger.log(values)
 return values
}
```

then I used following code in datatable.html

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).getData();

function createTable(dataArray) {
 var username = document.getElementById("username").value;    
    console.log(dataArray)
      $('#btn-close').click()
      $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        "oSearch": {"sSearch": username}, // data search according to username expected
      data: dataArray.slice(1),
     columns: [
      { title: "Number" }, //....more columns below.
```

**Observation**: No filtering. All data in sheet is displaying in the table.

**Check**: I replaced  `"oSearch": {"sSearch": username}` to  `"oSearch": {"sSearch": "user1"} //  user1 is one of username (data in the filtering column.)`
Data filtering as I want. //trying to obtain same result using USERNAME search

Please help me to filter row data according to specific column data (username) values.

Comment: getData() is undefined.  What does not working mean?  Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: From `Data search is always success when I edit code as below.` and `**"oSearch": {"sSearch": "satya" },**` and your showing script, in this case, how about cheking the value of `var username = document.getElementById("username").value;`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your updated question, about `I replaced "oSearch": {"sSearch": username} to "oSearch": {"sSearch": "user1"} //  user1 is one of username (data in the filtering column.) Data filtering as I want.` and your showing script, in this case, how about checking the value of `var username = document.getElementById("username").value;`?

Comment: Please provide your whole html code so we can replicate what you have.

Comment: @Twilight  Here's spreadheet link [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13P0q_U6B-WK14iU_6utndQ2s_dajlRQYN1LtiGz9ea4/edit?usp=sharing).